# В функцию аргументом передаем другую функцию что будет?

Tags: javascript

```js
function b(){
  return 2
}


function f(d){
  return d
}


f(b)
```

В функцию аргументом передаем другую функцию что будет ?

1. Функцию в глобальной области видимости передаем в качестве аргумента в другую функцию что будет ?
2. Как правильно передавать функцию в качестве аргумента в другую функцию ?

Comment: Подробнее с примером, пожалуйста. Какую функцию в какую функцию.

Comment: Будет функция переданная аргументом в другую функцию.

Comment: @Leks, в примере никакая функция не передается в качестве параметра.

Comment: @Leks, что правильно?

Comment: Для этого надо **передать** аргумент **при вызове** функции.

Comment: покажи аргументы, которые ты тут передаешь: `f()`

Comment: @Leks, и в чем теперь заключается вопрос?

Comment: если задача была передать функцию в качестве параметра - то да

Comment: точно также как и любую другую функцию, например, как ты вызываешь функцию `f`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
// функция, которая печатает что-то в консоль
function printRes1(res) { // ее передадим в другую функцию
  console.log('1_result is: ', res);
}

// еще одна функция, которая печатает что-то в консоль
function printRes2(res) { // ее передадим в другую функцию
  console.log('2_result: ' + res + ' is printed in another function');
}

// функция, которая складывает числа, но не умеет печатать результат
function add(a, b, cb) { // зато может принять колбэк (cb)
  console.log('in add func');
  let r = a + b;
  // здесь мы вызовем эту функцию и передадим результат сложения
  cb(r);
  console.log('after callback');
}

add(2, 2, printRes1);
add(2, 2, printRes2);
add(2, 2, (res) => { // передаём анонимную функцию
  console.log(res + ' in anonimous function');
});

// идея в том, что мы можем в какой-то функции получить какой-то результат,
// но с этим результатом мы хотим делать разные вещи. Например, вывести в консоль
// или отправить на сервер. Чтобы не писать под каждую задачу свою функцию, 
// мы можем этот результат поместить в коллбэк и уже в коллбэке делать с ним
// что хотим.
```