# Как вызвать функцию в функции?

Tags: javascript

Я пытаюсь решить следующую задачу:

> Реализуйте функцию-шпиона spy, которая работает следующим образом:
> принимает на вход любую функцию, например:
>
> ```
> function foo(a) {
>    return a;
> }
>
> const fooSpy = spy(foo);
> ```
>
> и может следить за ее вызовами
>
> ```
> fooSpy('test'); // return: test
> fooSpy.callCount(); // out: 1
> fooSpy.calledWith('test'); // out: true
> fooSpy.calledWith('test123'); // out: false
> fooSpy.returned('test'); // out: true
> ```

Как вызвать функцию в функции?

```
function spy(func) {
  // код функции здесь
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qbvsu7rt/23/ вот можете в консоли чекнуть

```js
function foo(a) {
  console.log(a);
  return a;
}

const fooSpy = spy(foo);

fooSpy('test'); // return: test
fooSpy.callCount(); // out: 1
fooSpy.calledWith('test'); // out: true
fooSpy.calledWith('test123'); // out: false
fooSpy.returned('test'); // out: true


function spy(func) {
  let fooSpy = {
    callCount: function() {
      console.log('testss')
    }
  }
  console.log(func);
  if (func === undefined) {
    console.log(1);
  }
  spy.prototype.callCount = function() {
    console.log('win')
  };
  return func;
}
fooSpy.prototype.callCount = function() {
  console.log('win')
};
```

Comment: покажите, пожалуйста, чего вы уже попробовали и почему это не сработало. Это учебная задача, и решать её за вас большого смысла нет, вы научитесь гораздо большему, если предпримите попытки и зададите более конкретный вопрос (более того, часто в процессе написания хорошего вопроса находится ответ)

Comment: @YakovL я вон закинул jsfiddle можете в консоли посмотреть

Comment: Я уже как-то отвечал на подобное [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/994649/%d0%92-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b1%d1%83%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82/994671#994671). Можешь глянуть. Вроде понятно должно быть.

Comment: (index):40 Uncaught TypeError: fooSpy.callCount is not a function
    at window.onload

Answer (score 1):

```
    function spy(func) {
      func()
    }
```

Comment: я уже делал func callCount() {} все равно ошибка та же { fooSpy is not a function }